# Gradle error trying to run nativescript app on android emulator on mac

Tags: android, macos, gradle, nativescript, kinvey

I'm trying to run a nativescript app on android using `tns run android`

I'm always getting gradle error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:

Build file: 

'/Volumes/My_SSD/myproject/platforms/tempPlugin/kinvey_nativescript_sdk/bui
ld.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating root project '`kinvey_nativescript_sdk`'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin']
   > Could not create service of type OutputFilesRepository using ExecutionServices.createOutputFilesRepository().`
```

I tried the following:

1. Run `./gradlew --stacktrace` but I got this error:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.LockTimeoutException: Timeout waiting to lock 
execution history cache 
(/Volumes/My_SSD/myproject/platforms/tempPlugin/kinvey_nativescript_sdk/.gr
adle/5.1.1/executionHistory). It is currently in use by another Gradle 
instance.
Owner PID: unknown
Our PID: 50331
Owner Operation: unknown
Our operation: 
Lock file: 
/Volumes/My_SSD/myproject/platforms/tempPlugin/kinvey_nativescript_sdk/.gra
dle/5.1.1/executionHistory/executionHistory.lock
```

2. Deleted .lock files manually and re-ran `tns run android` but I got the same error again
3. Run

```
chmod  R+x/Volumes/My_SSD/myproject/platforms/tempPlugin/kinvey_nativescript_sdk
```

Didn't fix the problem

The app runs fine on ios emulator and but not on android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem, looks to be related with [this Gradle issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4329).

The workaround I found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/tbuild-error-caused-by-gradle-buildoutputcleanup-cache-properties-lock/130444/2) is to move the project to the home folder (~).